# F# Sort an Array with foldBack or fold.

Tags: arrays, sorting, f#, append, fold

I am trying to sort an Array by using fold or foldBack.

I have tried achieving this like this:

```
let arraySort anArray = 
    Array.fold (fun acc elem -> if acc >= elem then acc.append elem else elem.append acc) [||] anArray
```

this ofcourse errors horribly. If this was a list then i would know how to achieve this through a recursive function but it is not.

So if anyone could enlighten me on how a workable function given to the fold or foldback could look like then i would be createful.

Before you start advising using `Array.sort anArray` then this wont do since this is a School assignment and therefore not allowed.

Comment: If you know how to do it with a list, why not convert to a list and then convert back to an array after you finish sorting?

Comment: Do you have F# 4.0?

Comment: Foggy I have F# 4.1

Comment: Ringil it sounds smart but I think my teacher fail me if i do that. The assignment says it must return a sorted version of the same array.

Comment: just show how you will make it to the list

Comment: acc is an array, so the comparison acc >= elem fails. I think you have to insert each element elem in the right place in the array acc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To answer the question

We can use `Array.fold` for a simple insertion sort-like algorithm:

```
let sort array =
    let insert array x =
        let lesser, greater = Array.partition (fun y -> y < x) array
        [| yield! lesser; yield x; yield! greater |]
    Array.fold insert [||] array
```

I think this was closest to what you were attempting.

---

#### A little exposition

Your comment that you have to return a sorted version of the same array are a little confusing here - F# is immutable by default, so `Array.fold` used in this manner will actually create a new array, leaving the original untouched.  This is much the same as if you'd converted it to a list, sorted it, then converted back.  In F# the array type is immutable, but the elements of an array are all mutable.  That means you can do a true in-place sort (for example by the library function `Array.sortInPlace`), but we don't often do that in F#, in favour of the default `Array.sort`, which returns a new array.

You have a couple of problems with your attempt, which is why you're getting a few errors.

First, the operation to append an array is very different to what you attempted.  We could use the `yield` syntax to append to an array by `[| yield! array ; yield element |]`, where we use `yield!` if it is an array (or in fact, any `IEnumerable`), and `yield` if it is a single element.

Second, you can't compare an array type to an element of the array.  That's a type error, because `compare` needs two arguments of the same type, and you're trying to give it a `'T` and a `'T array`.  They can't be the same type, or it'd be infinite (`'T = 'T array` so `'T array = 'T array array` and so on).  You need to work out what you should be comparing instead.

Third, even if you could compare the array to an element, you have a logic problem.  Your element either goes right at the end, or right at the beginning.  What if it is greater than the first element, but less than the last element?

As a final point, you can still use recursion and pattern matching on arrays, it's just not quite as neat as it is on lists because you can't do the classic `| head :: tail ->` trick.  Here's a basic (not-so-)quicksort implementation in that vein.

```
let rec qsort = function
    | [||] -> [||]
    | arr  ->
        let pivot = Array.head arr
        let less, more = Array.partition (fun x -> x < pivot) (Array.tail arr)
        [| yield! qsort less ; yield pivot ; yield! qsort more |]
```

The speed here is probably several orders of magnitude slower than `Array.sort` because we have to create many many arrays while doing it in this manner, which .NET's `Array.Sort()` method does not.

Comment: Thank you so much Jake. It all makes perfect sence! and yeah Array.sort FTW!